# Marketing Cloud Email and Web Recommendations product catalog refresh schedule is no longer working

Tags: marketing-cloud, einstein

I have a problem with clients' product catalog refresh schedule in Email/Web Recommendations.
It stopped working on daily intervals starting 16 Nov. When I click Save and Refresh it correctly downloads SFTP File and process it. But schedule is not firing file refresh nor send any error message to me. It just omits refresh. Anyone experience it? Dateof 16th Nov seems same like Marketing Cloud October Release update to reflect new SSL Custom Domains so maybe Marketing Cloud has some bug?

Comment: PS: I tried to change FTP password and update file refresh - still schedule is not refreshing - it just refresh once when click Save and Refresh

Comment: Have you engaged Salesforce Support?

Comment: just FYI SSL was not released on the 16th, so doubtful its related to a release

Comment: Just wondering if you were able to resolve this and what the cause was if you were.

Comment: Hi Mark P, it somehow started to refresh automatically but have not found solution so far. It sometimes stops, but after several manual refreshes it reverts back to automate. Will raise that case to Salesforce support cause my next client is issuing same behaviour. Will update here when find solution.

Comment: I got information from Salesforce Support that they had problems with it, but they fixed it. No information why, so somehow resolved.